# Using only available req.query objects as keys in redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis

I have a MERN application, and I am using redis to implement caching.
I have a router with req.query `(localhost:3000/persons?name=john&lastname=doe&age=18)`
With Redis i want to use only available objects inserted in url, I mean if in url we insert name key will be name; if we insert the 3 object keys will be : name, lastname, age.
there is various combination and i don't how i know to implement that i mean how to implement generic way to implement this or condition.

Comment: what do want exactly? do you want to insert  just name of key( name, lastname, age) in redis?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi i want to insert and get only keys in query if i execute set([name,lastname,age],cb) i got key lastname undefind because i passed the query without lastname

Comment: with `Object.keys(req.query)` you can get only keys, after that you can do what you want, I can understand what do you want exactly